# Performing operations involving absolute values

Tags: absolute-value

How do you perform operations involving absolute values? I want to avoid squaring them, is there any way to work around that?

Suppose I want to solve $\frac{|x-120|\cdot|y-39|}{2}$, what should be the expressions equivalent?

EDIT: apologies, suppose I want to simplify the expression above?

Additionally, suppose $z(x,y)=\frac{|x-120|\cdot|y-39|}{2} +\frac{|x-23|\cdot|y-11|}{2}$ and I want to find the optimal values for $(x,y)$. How do I go about it?

Comment: $|a| \cdot |b|=|a \cdot b|$.  I don't know what you are solving though.

Comment: What do you mean, you want to "solve" this?  Is there an equation somewhere?  Also, why do you want to avoid squaring absolute values?

Comment: @randomgirl edited the question

Comment: @saulspatz to avoid the problem from being too computationally intensive

Comment: you can always get rid of the absolute value bars by specifying constraints on $x$ and $y$. For example, $|x-120|=x-120$ if $x\ge 120$

Comment: You mean you want to minimize $z(x,y)$, correct?

Comment: Yes, but how do you take the derivative if we are to eliminate abs value bars with constraints? How would you even take the derivative?

Comment: You break $R^2$ into areas and find local max/min in those areas then find the global max/min. Let's say you have $f(x,y)=|x+1|+|y-2|$. You'll have four areas: a) $x<-1$, $y<2$; b)  $x<-1$, $y \ge2$; c)  $x\ge -1$, $y<2$; d)  $x\ge -1$, $y \ge 2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$z(120,11) = 0+0 = 0,$ which is clearly a minimum.